# using OR in an argument to a method

Tags: java, string, parameters

How can I include multiple terms as a single arguments to a method?

For example:
method is declared as follows:

```
 public void showSchedules(String day, String AMPM);
```

I want to call something like

```
showSchedules ("Monday" || "Tuesday", AM);
```

but the operators cannot be applied to java lang String.
Any tips?

Comment: Call the method multiple times? Rewrite the method to accept multiple strings?

Comment: What do you want to do...?

Comment: A good question on the grounds that you can arrange things in C++ so your second syntax *is* valid. Alas in Java it makes no sense, but why not pass a `String[]` instead, or even an interface that supports iteration?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are suggesting is not possible. The || operator in Java is a logical (boolean) operator. It evaluates the boolean expressions on either side (if necessary) and returns a boolean value. So your suggestion will never work since the expressions on each side are Strings and not booleans.

You have three options here:

1. Pass each argument individually into the method, or if you don't know how many there will be pass them in an array or some other collection.

```
showSchedules("Monday", "Tuesday", AM) {...}
```

or

```
showSchedules(new String[] {"Monday", "Tuesday"}, AM) {...}
```

2. Call the method twice, passing in one argument each time and then deal with the results in the calling method.
3. Invert the order of params and use **varargs**:

```
showSchedules(String AmPm, String... days) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Comment: One more follow up if you don't mind. How can I write "if String is equal to any items in the array"?


for example, given the following;

`String animal;
String[] animalArray = {"dog", "cat", "mouse"}; `


If animal is equal to any items in the animalArray, then do something...

Comment: Unfortunately arrays don't have any methods that provide a shortcut for this. So what you would have to do is iterate over the array and compare each element to what you are looking for. Alternatively you could use an ArrayList instead of an array. This has a contains() method which you returns true if the arraylist contains the object specified as a parameter.

Comment: @Jaumzera thanks for the edit, I couldn't get the formatting working properly. Also good to get option three from the other answer in there.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot do that in passing arguments. However you can only control the functionality.

For ex

```
public void showSchedules(String day, String AMPM) {
    if (day.equals("Monday") ||  day.equals("Tuesday") ) {
       //TODO
    }

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can totally do that with an varargs, like so:

day will be an array of strings and you can pass as many as you want

```
public void showSchedules(String AMPM, String... day) {
    // you'll have to iterate through them here
    for(String d:day)
{
  switch(d)
    {
        case "Monday":
        break;
        case "Tuesday":
        break;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: @SamOrozco varargs have to be in the final argument position

Comment: I see, That's my mistake.

Comment: A reasonable answer imho now you've corrected it. If you show how to iterate over the variable argument list then I'll upvote.